# Sanitize remote path passed as argument to VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

On macOS when trying to open a remote Linux session of VS code from the terminal, I cannot manage to sanatize the path passed as argument.

`code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] [path_on_remote]` opens VS code remote session at the specified path `path_on_remote` if the path does not contain any whitespace.

However, the following fails if the path contains any whitespace.

```
code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] "[path on remote]"
code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] "'[path on remote]'"
code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] \"[path on remote]\"
code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] [path\ on\ remote]
code --remote=ssh-remote+[remote_hostname] [path\\\ on\\\ remote]
```

As many other escape options that I have tried.